# Is NSAttributedString cross platform?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos

Say I serialize an NSAttributedString object to a data buffer using NSKeyedArchiver on iOS and save it with CloudKit. Then I access the same data buffer and unarchive it with NSKeyedArchiver to NSAttributedString on MacOs. Will this work?

Comment: Edge cases in serialization/de-serialization are quite common. I.e. 90% of it works, but there's one mis-implemented attribute that isn't portable that can ruin it once you release to production. You've never run into one? There are some enums for example, which are spelt the same way between UIKit and  AppKit, but with different integer backing values. I wouldn't treat any type as interoperable unless that's a documented guarantee. "It happens to work for the narrow playground use-case I tested it in" isn't enough to build confidence

Comment: @Alexander Thank you, I think the edge cases are too unpredictable so I'm going to implement a codable attributed string in order to encode it as a JSON object. Thanks again

Comment: @IanBastos That's not what I was suggesting. `NSAttributedString` may very well be safe to serialize and deserialize across platforms. I'm not saying it is or that it isn't, but it's a valid thing to double check. Though I think you should show what background research you did prior to asking this question.